# passing default object as function parameter es6 works but not as plain parameter

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I don't get it, why this works?

```
import React from 'react'

import './Card.scss'

export default ({ type = 'single' }) => (
  <div>{type}</div>
)
```

and this doesn't?

```
import React from 'react'

import './Card.scss'

export default ( type = 'single' ) => (
  <div>{type}</div>
)
```

Comment: The former uses parameter destructuring to achieve 'named parameters'.

Comment: Of course it works, you just have to call it differently?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a comment, you've said you're using it as a React component directly, e.g.:

```
<Card type="single" />
```

and

```
<Card/>
```

You need to use the destructured version (your first example) because React components are called with a single argument, an object containing the properties for the component (a blank object if you don't specify any properties). A non-destructured one doesn't make sense, the `type` you'd receive would be an object, not a string.

Here's a snippet demonstrating what React passes to the component, which should clarify why expecting a simple argument as a string won't work:

```js
let Example = (props) => (
  <div>props: [{JSON.stringify(props)}]</div>
);
let Card = ({type = "simple"}) => (
  <div>Type: [{type}]</div>
);
ReactDOM.render(
  <div>
    <Example />
    <Example answer="42" />
    <Card type="simple" />
  </div>
  ,
  document.getElementById("react")
);
```

```html
<div id="react"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```

---

Original answer before you clarified you were using this directly as a component:

Both *work*, it's a matter of how you call each of them.<sup>1</sup>

Your first example should be called like this:

```
import thingy from 'somewhere';
thingy({type: 'double'});
//     ^--------------^---- note it's an object
```

...because it destructures its argument.

Your second example should be called like this:

```
import thingy from 'somewhere';
thingy('double');
//     ^------^---- note it's not an object
```

...because it just uses a simple argument.

<s>Separately: Your first example doesn't have a default value for the argument, so you can't call it with no arguments at all:</s>

```
// Doesn't work for the first example
thingy();
```

If you wanted to be able to do that, you'd need to supply an overall default:

```
export default ({ type = 'single' } = {}) => (
// Overall default ----------------^^^^^
  <div>{type}</div>
)
```

But your second example can be called with no arguments at all, because it has a default for its only argument.

*(That doesn't matter, React always calls it with a single object argument.)*

Comment: Its a react component, so its called like this: `<Card type="double"/>`

Comment: as react component default works fine the way I've it written :S `<Card/>` if I do that it correctly outputs default `single`.

Comment: thank you, even your original answer had cleared it up for me, but updated one deserved upvote too ^_^